# Angular directive USA telephone number

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I found the solution for USA telephone numbers, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask?file=app%2Fphone-mask.directive.ts).

But how can I add "+1" to the beginning of the telephone mask?
So it should be like: +1(123) 234-2345

Comment: Just prepend it before output? See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-aemug5

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't Work. Just to play with component and use also backspace key. Also, try enter 123123123123 and you will see all values become 11111111.
If it could be so simple I didnt post it.

Comment: So, the code you have is buggy :(

Comment: The code I posted works perfectly. But i need to add "+1" to the mask. So, the code I posted requires modification.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove it if its there:

```
if (event.startsWith('+1')) {
  newVal = newVal.substring(1); 
}
```

Then prepend it in the end:

```
newVal = '+1 ' + newVal;
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-xxbow9?file=app/phone-mask.directive.ts).

Comment: Your hint was really cool. But I need a mask for Angular Material Input component. What do you think about it ?